# Avoid Visual Studio warning on dynamic object initialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm creating a dynamic JObject:

```
dynamic request = new JObject();
request.UserId = 3;
```

But, while compiling the IDE gives me the hint:

> IDE0017 Object initialization can be simplified

When it happens, I normally solve it initializing the object properties together with object construction. Like:

```
var request = new FooObject {UserId = 3};
```

The problem is, as it is a dynamic object I create the properties dynamically, so it gives me an error saying that I can use the same approach, as:

```
dynamic request = new JObject {UserId = 3};
```

How to keep the dynamic approach and avoid the IDE warning ?

Comment: Supposedly fixed, but I am seeing the same behavior. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/17860 I guess supress...

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be1af3dc-891a-4ea3-8955-d69141d5909a/vs-2017-how-do-you-surpress-the-warning-object-initialization-can-be-simplified?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: ok! so by now it's not possible to initialize dynamic objects like that. By the current situation it's an IDE bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this rule on your VS 2017 going to Tools->Options->TextEditor->C#->CodeStyle->Prefer object initializer